# Как распарсить String array в BigInteger?

Tags: java, массивы, biginteger

Как можно преобразовать массив строк в массив `BigInteger`?

Если в массив `int`, то я делаю это так:

```java
String[] arrStr = {"7", "3"};

int[] arrInt = new int[arrStr.length];

for (int i = 0; i < arrInt.length; i++)

    arrInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(arrStr[i]);
```

В массив `BigInteger` так не получается.

Comment: Вы хотите узнать как преобразовать строку в `BigInteger`? Или у Вас с массивом проблемы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно просто в вашем примере сменить тип массива на `BigInteger`, и при инициализации элементов этого массива вызывать конструктор, принимающий `String`:

```
String[] arrStr = {"7", "3"};

BigInteger[] arrBigInt = new BigInteger[arrStr.length];

for (int i = 0; i < arrBigInt.length; i++) {

    arrBigInt[i] = new BigInteger(arrStr[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант с помощью Java Stream API

```java
String[] arrStr = {"7", "3"};
BigInteger[] arrBigInt = Arrays.stream(arrStr)
        .map(s -> new BigInteger(s))
        .toArray(BigInteger[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Получаем массив `BigInteger[]` из массива `String[]`:

```java
String[] arrStr = {"7", "3"};

BigInteger[] arr = Arrays.stream(arrStr)
        .map(BigInteger::new)
        .toArray(BigInteger[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // [7, 3]
```